# CloudDeploy[FormFunction[ ]] not working

Tags: wolfram-cloud

What is wrong with this code:

```
CloudDeploy[FormFunction[{"Number1"->"Number","Number2"->"Number"},
                         If[#Number1/#Number2<=0.5,"True","False"]]]
```

It gives back the following error:

> Function::slot1: (CloudObject`Private`setCloudIcon[Last[#1],CloudObject`Private`cloud$15017,CloudObject`Private`uuid$15017,First[#1],\[Ellipsis] t-><<37>>,Deployment->CloudObject`Private`deployment$15017,Asynchronous->True,Content->FormFunction[Number1 Number2 ,If[Slot[<<1>>] Power[<<2>>]<=0.5,True,False]],Deployment->WebForm]&)[<<1>>] is expected to have an Association as the first argument.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please write a title that has something to do with the content of your question and will help future questioners find the answer from your title.

Answer (score 4):

use postfix `&` pure function or fullform pure `Function`.

```
CloudDeploy[
  FormFunction[
    {"Number1" -> "Number", "Number2" -> "Number"}, 
    If[#Number1/#Number2 <= 0.5, "True", "False"] &
  ]
]
```

```
CloudDeploy[
  FormFunction[
    {"Number1" -> "Number", "Number2" -> "Number"}, 
    Function[If[#Number1/#Number2 <= 0.5, "True", "False"]]
  ]
]
```